# Problem running django and apache2 on ubuntu vps

Tags: python, linux, apache

Everything was running fine until I changed `debug to false` in my `settings.py`,
and then it started to give me 500 error.

here are my `apaceh2` error logs:

```
�[Tue Mar 03 06:25:02.485411 2020] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 10324:tid 1406234922$
[Tue Mar 03 06:25:02.485468 2020] [core:notice] [pid 10324:tid 140623492262848]$
[Tue Mar 03 15:35:36.999779 2020] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 10324:tid 14062349226$
[Tue Mar 03 15:35:37.136460 2020] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 17751:tid 14043275382$
[Tue Mar 03 15:35:37.136617 2020] [core:notice] [pid 17751:tid 140432753822656]$
[Tue Mar 03 15:38:50.936939 2020] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 17751:tid 14043275382$
[Tue Mar 03 15:38:51.232326 2020] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 17953:tid 14045334320$
[Tue Mar 03 15:38:51.232453 2020] [core:notice] [pid 17953:tid 140453343202240]$
[Tue Mar 03 15:58:26.856374 2020] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 17953:tid 14045334320$
[Tue Mar 03 15:58:27.208755 2020] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 18264:tid 14000472418$
[Tue Mar 03 15:58:27.208886 2020] [core:notice] [pid 18264:tid 140004724181952]$
[Tue Mar 03 15:58:56.397005 2020] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 18264:tid 14000472418$
[Tue Mar 03 15:58:56.570087 2020] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 18394:tid 14039951731$
[Tue Mar 03 15:58:56.570221 2020] [core:notice] [pid 18394:tid 140399517318080]$
[Tue Mar 03 16:00:03.116971 2020] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 18394:tid 14039951731$
[Tue Mar 03 16:00:03.314127 2020] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 18566:tid 13997802622$
[Tue Mar 03 16:00:03.314250 2020] [core:notice] [pid 18566:tid 139978026220480]$
[Tue Mar 03 19:56:44.142384 2020] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 18566:tid 13997802622$
[Tue Mar 03 19:56:44.249434 2020] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 20655:tid 14032566712$
```

and here is my `site.conf` file that has the Virtual host settings:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName www.g-attend.com
        ServerAlias g-attend.com
        Alias /static /home/litoo00/g_attend/prod/g-attend/g_attend/static/
        <Directory /home/litoo00/g_attend/prod/g-attend/g_attend/static>
        Require all granted
        </Directory>
        <Directory /home/litoo00/g_attend/prod/g-attend/g_attend/g_attend/>
           <Files wsgi.py>
              Require all granted
           </Files>
        </Directory>
        WSGIDaemonProcess g_attend python-home=/home/litoo00/g_attend/prod/g-at$
        WSGIProcessGroup g_attend
        WSGIScriptAlias / /home/litoo00/g_attend/prod/g-attend/g_attend/g_atten$
        <Directory /home/litoo00/g_attend/prod/g-attend/g_attend/>
                Order deny,allow
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName www.g-attend.com
        ServerAlias g-attend.com
        Alias /static /home/litoo00/g_attend/prod/g-attend/g_attend/static/
        <Directory /home/litoo00/g_attend/prod/g-attend/g_attend/static>
        Require all granted
        </Directory>
        <Directory /home/litoo00/g_attend/prod/g-attend/g_attend/g_attend/>
           <Files wsgi.py>
              Require all granted
           </Files>
        </Directory>
        WSGIDaemonProcess g_attend python-home=/home/litoo00/g_attend/prod/g-at$
        WSGIProcessGroup g_attend
        WSGIScriptAlias / /home/litoo00/g_attend/prod/g-attend/g_attend/g_atten$
        <Directory /home/litoo00/g_attend/prod/g-attend/g_attend/>
                Order deny,allow
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName www.g-attend.com
        ServerAlias g-attend.com
        Alias /static /home/litoo00/g_attend/prod/g-attend/g_attend/static/
        <Directory /home/litoo00/g_attend/prod/g-attend/g_attend/static>
        Require all granted
        </Directory>
        <Directory /home/litoo00/g_attend/prod/g-attend/g_attend/g_attend/>
           <Files wsgi.py>
              Require all granted
           </Files>
        </Directory>
        WSGIDaemonProcess g_attend python-home=/home/litoo00/g_attend/prod/g-at$
        WSGIProcessGroup g_attend
        WSGIScriptAlias / /home/litoo00/g_attend/prod/g-attend/g_attend/g_atten$
        <Directory /home/litoo00/g_attend/prod/g-attend/g_attend/>
                Order deny,allow
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
        WSGIDaemonProcess g_attend python-home=/home/litoo00/g_attend/prod/g-at$
        WSGIProcessGroup g_attend
        WSGIScriptAlias / /home/litoo00/g_attend/prod/g-attend/g_attend/g_atten$
        <Directory /home/litoo00/g_attend/prod/g-attend/g_attend/>
                Order deny,allow
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
        DocumentRoot /home/litoo00/g_attend/prod/g-attend/g_attend/
        ErrorLog /home/litoo00/g_attend/prod/g-attend/g_attend/error.log
        CustomLog /home/litoo00/g_attend/prod/g-attend/g_attend/custom.log comb$
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/www_g-attend_com.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/g-attend.key
        SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/www_g-attend_com.ca-bundle
</VirtualHost>
```

**note** i have added custom 404 and 500 html and handlers in django.

Comment: What about the logs from your wsgi process?

Comment: Also, I think those `$` at the end of the line is whatever tool you are using showing that the line is being truncated. Use a tool that shows the full lines when posting.